# Nginx map redirect capture regex/query string capture and redirect to new

Tags: nginx, redirect, nginx-module

I am trying to setup bulk redirections in nginx(openresty) with map directive but am facing some issues  with capturing regex/query string from the source url and forward to destination url. below is like my setup

**nginx.conf is like**

```
map_hash_bucket_size 512;
map_hash_max_size 32768;
map $uri $new_redirects {
  default "none";
  include /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/new_redirect.map;
   }
```

**Server Block**

```
if ($new_redirects != "none") {
   return 301 $scheme://$http_host$new_redirects;
   }
```

new redirect map contains below redirects

`~^/test/123/(\w+)(\w+).*$ /US/en/test/$1-$2;`

Which is working good
but i am struggling a lot to get for the below strings

1. Part of url for Regex Capture

`/Product.html?ProdNo=A5441&Brand=COMPANY`

Captures in the new url

```
/US/en/product/COMPANY-A5441
```

2.Part of url for Regex Capture

```
/ProductDetail.do?&N5=SEARCH_CONCAT_PNO|BRAND_KEY&F=SPEC&N4=AV35016|COMPANY
```

Captures in the new url

```
/US/en/product/COMPANY-AV35016
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Cheers all!

Comment: `$uri` does not contain the query string - you should use `$request_uri` with `map`.

Comment: @RichardSmith thanks but how do i capture the strings in the main part and forward to the new url